# Caching view in ionic not working for first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am working on an app that I am building from the ionic framework.
I have a three tabbed view.

1. list
2. filter
3. tab3

The scenario is for the first time when I go to list state from filter state and then I select one item from the list and go the list detail page and I click on the back button from detail, this time I go back to list page but the list reloads means the state reloads.

But If I do this for the second time the list doesn't reload and the state cache has been saved properly.

It only happens for the first time. I don't know what could be the reason can anyone help me with this?

```
.state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.parentTab', {
      url: '/parent',
      cache: true,
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'parent.html',
          controller: 'parentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.parentTab.list', {
      url: '/list',
      cache: true,
      views: {
          'search-units': {
            templateUrl: "list.html",
            controller: 'listCtrl'
          }
        },
    })
    .state('app.parentTab.listFilter', {
      url: '/listFilter',
      authRequired: false,
      cache: true,
      views: {
        'search-filter': {
          templateUrl: "filter.html",
          controller: 'filterCtrl'
        }
      },
    })
    .state('app.parentTab.tab3', {
      url: '/tab3',
      cache: false,
      views: {
        'search-map': {
          templateUrl: "tab3.html",
          controller: 'tab3Ctrl'
        }
      },
    })
    .state('app.detail', {
      url: '/detail',
      cache: false,
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "details.html",
          controller: 'detailsCtrl'
        }
      },
    })
```

Comment: You should use the ion view events and lifecycle, please refer this blog post https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/09/08/working-around-ionics-cached-views

Comment: @Akil Can you please tell me how do I use ion view events and lifecycle to handle cache?

Comment: Add the required lifecycle (beforeenter , onenter , etc)method and put your code within it, the tutorial is provided in my previous comment.